# What is the correct syntax for converting an inline php email variable from mysql to pdo?

Tags: mysql, email, pdo

I'm converting from mysql recordsets to pdo. This recordset is no longer properly named to feed data to the outgoing email object and I need help to know how to re-name the variable in the outgoing email.

Previously the mysql recordset said:

```
$row_rsFindEmailRec = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsFindEmailRec);
```

and the outgoing $emailObj->setContent()  said:

```
"Your last address was: {rsFindEmailRec.email_address}"
```

That showed up correctly in the email with the users last address.

Currently the pdo recordset says:

```
$row_rsFindEmailRec = $stmtFindEmailRec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

but since the actual recordset name is rsFindEmailRec, the email goes out, but the email arrives and the actual code shows {rsFindEmailRec.email_address} instead of the value.

I'm trying to change the inline, php variable in the email,

```
{rsFindEmailRec.email_address}
```

to whatever it should be for this new pdo style, but nothing I've tried works, and, I've tried some fairly laughable options in the inline php in the content line, as well as changes to the $stmt:

```
{email_address} (but it's not part of the transaction and can't be made so)
{$rsFindEmailRec.email_address}
{$row_rsFindEmailRec.email_address} which I can make work but it causes other issues downstream that I'd rather avoid.

stmtFindEmailRec.email_address}
{$stmtFindEmailRec.email_address}
```

and I've tried to alter the head code to reflect my wishful thinking:

```
$rsFindEmailRec = $stmtFindEmailRec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); alone and both above and below the $row_rs(etc) but nope.
$rsFindEmailRec = $row_rsFindEmailRec;
```

Like Thomas Edison, I've discovered a whole bunch of new ways not to do it, but not the correct one. Time for Stack: 
How do I rename {rsFindEmailRec.email_address} for this PDO? or
What source variable should I be using to replace the one in the outgoing email to show the value of the variable in the email message?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe you used single quotes? single quoted strings are not interpolated in php

Comment: @meda Nope, it's double quoted.

Comment: `$row_rsFindEmailRec['email_address']` should work as well

Comment: @meda
Thanks meda, yes, that is the only one I could make work, but I'm reluctant to use it because these emails are stored in an include file and the other page that use that file report an undefined variable since they don't have the same recordset. 

I can, of course, move all the emails out of the single page and into a set of individual pages, but that is sort of self-defeating on other grounds. I can also just accept that there is a notice that will disappear when I turn off error reporting, but that seems cheesy, too. Any other ideas how to do this or have we seen them all?